# winApi create process using c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to open a picture using WinApi in c++, tried both **createProcessW** and **createProcessA**, my main problem was concatenating the strings that are used as cmdLine parameter. this is what iv'e got:

```
STARTUPINFOW process_startup_info{ 0 };
process_startup_info.cb = sizeof(process_startup_info); // setup size of strcture in bytes

PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info{ 0 };

wchar_t* s = L"\"C:\\Windows\\system32\\mspaint.exe\" ";
std::string s2 = pic.getPath();
// connecting strings here
if (CreateProcessW(NULL, /* string should be here */, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &process_startup_info, &process_info))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(process_info.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(process_info.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(process_info.hThread);
}
```

Comment: You need to convert the path to the picture to a wide string before you can concatenate the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the same types everywhere for the command and the params if you can. Here I am using a `wstring`, concatenating a parameter to the command then casting it to `LPWSTR` for the CreateProcess method.

```
STARTUPINFOW process_startup_info{ 0 };
process_startup_info.cb = sizeof(process_startup_info); // setup size of strcture in bytes

PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info{ 0 };

std::wstring params = L"\"C:\\Windows\\system32\\mspaint.exe\" ";
params.append(L"\"C:\\Vroom Owl.png\"");

// connecting strings here
if (CreateProcessW(NULL, (LPWSTR)params.data(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &process_startup_info, &process_info))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(process_info.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(process_info.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(process_info.hThread);
}
```

Comment: Setting the project to multi-byte instead of Unicode will make `CreateProcess()` call `CreateProcessA()` instead of `CreateProcessW()`. It is actually better NOT to rely on the `TCHAR` macros. In this case, if you use `std::wstring` then you *should* call `CreateProcessW()` directly to match. Also note that using `const_cast<LPWSTR>(params.c_str())` is technically undefined behavior, use `params.data()` (C++17 or later) or `&params[0]` (C++11 or later) instead (`std::(w)string` data was not *guaranteed* to be stored in sequential memory prior to C++11, but it usually was in practice).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I can get on board with that. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Don't cast away `const`-ness if you can help it. If your compiler has a `data()` method available but not a non-`const` version of it, using `&[0]` will work and no cast needed of it.

Answer (score 0):

In include :

```
#include <sstream>
```

In code:

```
std::wstringstream wstringCmd;

std::wstring wstrExec = L"\"C:\\Windows\\system32\\mspaint.exe\" "; //<- wstring 
std::string strPic = pic.getPath(); //<- if getPath() return char  
// std::wstring wstrPic = pic.getPath();//<- if getPath() return wchar  

// you can combine as you like ...
wstringCmd << wstrExec.c_str() << strPic.c_str(); // or << wstrPic.c_str();
std::wstring wstrCommande= wstringCmd.str();
```

Comment: I'm confused by the strPic and wstrPic values here. The method calls are enclosed in double quotes. Surely that was an oversight.

Comment: Also, you can't stream a `std::string` or `char*` into a `std::wstringstream`, either. You would have to convert the `std::string` to `std::wstring` first

Comment: @NTDLS it was just to explain that we have "string" or L"string"

Comment: @RemyLebeau try it, if it doesn't work, we'll talk about it again

Comment: @Landstalker [I did try it](https://ideone.com/bxX39e), and OK granted, `<<` works for `char*` even when the stream is `std::wstringstream`, but it does not work for `std::string`. Also, you can't save a `std::wstring` from `std::wstringstream.str()` to a `std::string`.

Comment: *but it does not work for std::string* -> i don't use string but `string.c_str()`  | *you can't save a std::wstring from std::wstringstream.str() to a std::string* --> I didn't put that in the code.  maybe you’re talking about how it works in general and not just the code at the top